# netsh portforwarding not working while accessing url from mobile

Tags: networking, virtualbox, portforwarding, netsh, windows-networking

**Problem statement**:
I have an Oracle VM running on my windows machine. And the VM machine has an application running in jboss. I want to access this application (running on VM) on my mobile.

**What I had tried**:
I tried port forwarding using below commands and it is working perfectly when I access this from Desktop browser(http://{hostmachineip or localhost}:9098 is connecting to jboss on VM). Now if I access this from my Mobile browser(connected to Desktop wifi hotspot and url-- http://hostmachineip:9098), it is not working.

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=9098 connectaddress=&lt;IP of VM&gt;

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=9098 listenaddress=&lt;IP of Host Machine&gt; connectaddress=&lt;IP of VM&gt; connectport=9098
```

**Oracle VM network settings:**

Attached to : Host-only Adapter

Promiscuous Mode: Deny

I'm not supposed to change Adapter to Bridged Adapter as the IP for VM will change and it has a major impact in my existing project.

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with windows firewall. opened 9098 port and it started working. 
[Link](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html) describing steps to open port.